# Parse video name and url from JSON

Tags: php, json

I need help to parse the names and URLs of videos from some JSON data.

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('http://odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=videoPlayerMetadata&mid=507252337');

$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach($obj->videos as $videos){
    $string = $videos->url;

$arr = explode('clientType=0',$string);
$string = implode('clientType=0", type:"mp4"},',$arr);
$arr = explode('http',$string);
$string = implode('{ file: "http',$arr);
echo $string;
}
?>
```

I need also the "name":

```
"name":"lowest"
"name":"low"
"name":"sd"
"name":"hd"
```

original url:

http://odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=videoPlayerMetadata&mid=507252337

you can test it here:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/JDiU4h

Comment: works, but i want also the name of every url look http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=videoPlayerMetadata&mid=507252337

Comment: You do realise that you've overwritten the `$string` variable twice, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create another json based on another data like the one you have on your fiddle, don't create the json string by hand. Gather the necessary values that you want inside another container then re encode again.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=videoPlayerMetadata&mid=507252337'), true);
$return = array();
foreach($data['videos'] as $videos){
    $filename = $videos['name'];
    $url = $videos['url'];
    $type = 'mp4';

    $return[] = array(
        'file' => $url,
        'type' => $type,
        'name' => $filename,
    );
}

echo json_encode($return);

// echo '<pre>';
// echo json_encode($return, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/38f241)

Comment: ok, another question... why the video url works on godaddy and not on another host?

Comment: @VincenzoPiromalli what do you mean by that? its not accessible on another host? what does the page say?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

   $json = file_get_contents('http://odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=videoPlayerMetadata&mid=507252337');

   $obj = json_decode($json);
   foreach($obj->videos as $video){
      echo $video->name .' :: '. $video->url;
      echo '<br>';
   }
?>
```

`$video` variable is an `stdClass` object, this means you can retrieve another values by `$video->value`.

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine, but links doesn't
I guess ok.ru are using some kind of a hack